# VNC session from Win to Fedora locks out in a short while - how to increase session inactivity timeout?

Tags: linux, fedora, vnc

VNC session from Win to Fedora locks out in a short while.
Following works but is tedious to do this repeatedly

```
-bash$ loginctl list-sessions
   SESSION        UID USER             SEAT
         1      17666 u1
      1140      60046 u2
      1186      60046 u3
      1185      60046 u4
        c1         42 gdm              seat0

5 sessions listed.
-bash$ sudo loginctl unlock-session 1140
-bash$ sudo loginctl unlock-session 1186
-bash$ sudo loginctl unlock-session 1185
-bash$
```

I increased the `ClientAliveInterval` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but:

```
-bash$ sudo service sshd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart sshd.service
Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status sshd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Any way to increase the timeout of the session.

Comment: So, what does `systemctl status sshd.service` show after the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works

```
loginctl list-sessions              <- this get session numbers
loginctl unlock-session <session #> <- this unlocks the session
```

This unlocks the session in general and same is reflected on vnc as well.